# How to trigger SendTaskSuccess by an EventBridge Event without Lambda?

Tags: aws-step-functions

I want to resume the execution of a paused StateMachine (AWS StepFunctions) using an EventBridge Message.

In order to do this, I require:

1. Write a Lambda Function to call "SendTaskSuccess" on StepFunctions API and provide TaskToken.
2. Create an EventBridge rule to trigger the Lambda when the matching event is received.

I First thought an EventBridge Rule that directly sends "SendTaskSuccess" to StepFunctions would exist, but it's not the case. The Lambda function seems to be required.

Is there a simpler way?
Am I missing something?

Thanks!